# Why does mysql_query() return TRUE with a SELECT statement?

Tags: php, mysql

According to the manual of [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query) and to everything I know about this function that I used so many times, it can either return a resource or `FALSE` if the query is a `SELECT`. Yet it returns `TRUE` from time to time.

How can this be? It never ever happened before. Is this a bug in PHP 5.3.2? Does anyone know anything about this?

The code is something like:

```
if (!$resource = mysql_query($query, $handle)) {
    throw some exception;
}

var_dump($query);
if ($resource === true && strpos($query, 'SELECT') !== false) {
    throw new Exception('mysql_query() returned TRUE for SELECT');
}
```

It's pretty hard to reproduce, too. It happens only from time to time. I also noticed that it's likely this happens at the same time the server interrupts the connection suddenly, in which case it should return `FALSE`...

Comment: Are you sure it is the query you are working with returning true? As true should only be for the insert update or delete. I would check and make sure that you are not seeing a variable carry over from a previous statement.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that it returns TRUE? Show a snippet where you think this happens.

Comment: Added a snippet. The `var_dump()` clearly shows a normal `SELECT` query that I run in a normal MySQL client with normal results.

Comment: If you explicitly set `$resource` to -1 before that query, can you still reproduce it? I'm wondering in the case where the server is interrupted whether the value is actually changed or just not updated.

Comment: @Mel, just tried. It's still `TRUE`.

Comment: Try dumping mysql_error() when you get TRUE see if there is an unexpected error.

Comment: @James, good idea. The error is: `Lost connection to MySQL server during query.`. If this happens though, the manual states (and this was always the case) that `mysql_query()` will return `FALSE`, not `TRUE`... It does however confirm the suspicion that this strange behavior happens if the server suddenly drops the connection...

Comment: Are you by chance using pconnect?  I ran into a similar weird problem (however with a mssql box) that was using persistent connection and had intermittent network disconnects.

Comment: @Radu Just out of curiosity, have you tried it, without the result being in an `if` statement? Actually, I think that is the problem. The `!$resource = blah` so basically, if it cannot be set, then it returns true. Sort of a like a double negative.

Comment: @James, no, I'm using `mysql_connect()`.

Comment: @Brad, yes, the error was propagated to a part in the application that expected a resource, but, for the first time in a few years, got a value of `TRUE` instead of the expected resource. Which had me start debugging.

Comment: @James, I just tried again, but this time `mysql_error()` returned nothing, and still the result from `mysql_query()` was `TRUE`. I also tried with `mysql_pconnect()`. Same thing.

Comment: @Radu, check my answer below and see what happens.

Comment: What is the value of $handle when $resource === true?

Comment: @James, the handle is a `"resource(57) of type (mysql link) "`.

Comment: I tried passing a FALSE value as the handle parameter to mysql_query and it returns NULL - yet another undocumented return value (but at least it's a bit more obvious that something failed)

Comment: @James, at least that's undocumented... The fact that it returns `TRUE` is against the documented behavior...

Comment: I think that this is a rare occasion that it would have been hard to catch, I mean I cannot actively reproduce this error. But yea, I would say that it would be something to bring up to the PHP guys as either an undocumented 'feature' or a bug in the mysql class. Since the mysql class is sort of out dated, (given mysqli), they may disregard it, but on the other hand they may update their documentation. It is a good, but rare find. What you *can* do, which would be a real pita, is check `mysql_error` prior to querying. But yea, that would be a pain. Are the databases on the same server?

Comment: After reading your comment re: the code is quite old, I would start looking into what else happened "today" that could have caused general weirdness - network connectivity problems, database corruption, server problems, that kind of thing.  As Brad Jacobs says why is your mysql server dropping connections?

Comment: @James, likely due to too many open connections.

Comment: I do need to debug it... This problem appeared while I was debugging another problem, but still, the `mysql_query()` function does something completely strange that should not be possible... I very much wonder why...

Comment: @Radu, Thinking some more about it, you can add checks for type. IE `is_resource` instead of the `mysql_error` check. So in your if statement, just do something like `if (!$resource = mysql_query... || !is_resource($resource)) { // error here` Not sure how easy that would be to setup. But could be viewed as a bandaid. If it is due to too many connections, is there a way for you to up those connections? As far as strange behavior, indeed. I am trying to reproduce it so it can be brought up as bug or something similar and be documented.

Comment: Well, I am already throwing that exception if this strange behavior happens, so the bandaid has been applied... I will also continue debugging the original problem that led to this, which will likely result in less connections, which will make the problem go away. But then again... The strange behavior bugs me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If webbiedave isn't on the right track, there's only one codepath that allows for this situation in the php source:

```
#if MYSQL_VERSION_ID < 32224
#define PHP_MYSQL_VALID_RESULT(mysql)       \
    (mysql_num_fields(mysql)>0)
#else
#define PHP_MYSQL_VALID_RESULT(mysql)       \
    (mysql_field_count(mysql)>0)
#endif
```

...

```
if (!mysql_result) {
    if (PHP_MYSQL_VALID_RESULT(mysql->conn)) { /* query should have returned rows */
        php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "Unable to save result set");
        RETURN_FALSE;
    } else {
        RETURN_TRUE; // <<< this case
    }
}
```

I would consider this a bug. Especially since there's no real way to verify this - mysql_num_fields in the PHP code uses the resource that you're not getting, not the connection.

Although it's still weird that the C version of mysql_query returns zero on lost connection - if you're able to, try the following patch and reinstall the mysql extension:

```
Index: ext/mysql/php_mysql.c
===================================================================
--- ext/mysql/php_mysql.c       (revision 311719)
+++ ext/mysql/php_mysql.c       (working copy)
@@ -1485,6 +1485,9 @@
                if (PHP_MYSQL_VALID_RESULT(mysql->conn)) { /* query should have returned rows */
                        php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "Unable to save result set");
                        RETURN_FALSE;
+               } else if( mysql_errno(mysql->conn) != 0 ) {
+                       php_error_docref("http://www.mysql.com/doc" TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "%s", mysql_error(mysql->conn));
+                       RETURN_FALSE;
                } else {
                        RETURN_TRUE;
                }
```

Comment: Actually `MYSQL_VERSION_ID` is defined as `MYSQLND_VERSION_ID` which is defined as `50007`. So it should go on the `mysql_field_count()` branch.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `mysql_field_count()` function does (will look it up), but if it does what the name says it does, wouldn't `mysql_field_count(mysql)` be `0` if a problem occurred?

Comment: @Radu Modified the patch, had an error in there, mysql_error should be mysql_errno. And yes, field_count should be zero. This is a classic case of something that shouldn't happen, but I think we're in that realm with this bug.

Comment: @Radu I see what you mean. Field count is always zero in this case. It will still trigger the warning though. But also on non-select queries. Basically, the query is valid but not even a field count is received.

Comment: @Mel, `Error with field count > 0: field count = 0`

Comment: @Mel - shouldn't your check of mysql_errno be inside the first if clause?  if the result has field count > 0, PHP_MYSQL_VALID_RESULT() should succeed, so it will go down that code path

Comment: @David No, there are two cases. One is where the result set can't be saved, but the field count is set. The other is this case, most likely caused by a combination of using more then one database in the query and packets that are too large. They should have different error messages to distinguish between the cases but they should both return false. Going to update the patch to give a more useful error message.

Comment: @Mel, it's now `Lost connection to MySQL server during query`. So it *is* a PHP bug, isn't it?

Comment: @Radu Not really sure where to put the blame card. As said, I suspect this bug to be caused by using >1 database in the query and as such is inconsistent behavior of the libmysql's `mysql_query` function. But until we can prove it only happens with multiple databases in a query, it is indeed a PHP bug.

Comment: @Mel, but the query is not using multiple databases. There *are* multiple databases and multiple separated queries on different databases, but not one query on many databases.

Comment: @Mel, from my limited understanding though, it seems that they should have handled this strange behavior, right? They probably don't expect it, since `mysql_query()` returns `0` (success), so it looks like that's why they didn't check for it. Seems like `mysql_query()` returns success, but at the same time `mysql_errno()` is not `0`.

Comment: @Mel, looks like a `libmysqlclient` but. At the same time `mysql_query()` returns no error but `mysql_errno()` says there is an error.

Comment: @Radu ah yes. If there is not multiple databases involved, then it is a PHP bug, since they don't provide for this case. It is actually described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/null-mysql-store-result.html) but it's kind of ambiguous. On one hand they say "mysql_field_count == 0 means not a select query" and then go on to say "you can test for errors".

Comment: I have no control over the server. It doesn't even have the mysqli or pdo_mysql extensions. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Additionally, looking at the added lines, this doesn't seem like it would fix it for me, because mysql_error is 0 since the query executed fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you say it "returns TRUE," how are you testing that?  You're not by any chance doing something like this, are you?

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result == TRUE) { /* stuff */ }
```

If so, keep in mind that all non-zero, non-blank, non-null value that is returned will evaluate to TRUE.  You can verify this by using the more stringent:

```
if ($result === TRUE) { /* stuff */ }
```

That evaluates not just equivalence, but type as well.  Are you doing something like a var_export($result); to check the data type and verify that you're actually getting back the boolean value of TRUE?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this the other way, When [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query) returns `FALSE` it means that for what ever reason, the attempt to query has failed. Meaning that even before it got to do you're query something went wrong, as such there has been no effect on the database, or that the query was unable to even get to a point where it could see the database.

Comment: Yes, that is the expected behavior. However, `mysql_query()` returns `TRUE`, not `FALSE`.

Comment: @Radu, don't forget, `!$resource = mysql_query($query, $handle)` equates to `TRUE` if mysql_query returns `FALSE`.

Comment: mysql_query() can return false and modify the database. If you insert data into a MyISAM table and hit an error (duplicate unique key, etc) after inserting a few rows, mysql_query() returns false (and an error) but the rows stay in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned data lengths but you should check to see if this is called by an exceeding of `max_allowed_packet`.

> When a MySQL client or the mysqld
>   server receives a packet bigger than
>   max_allowed_packet bytes, it issues a
>   Packet too large error and closes the
>   connection. With some clients, **you may
>   also get a Lost connection to MySQL
>   server during query error if the
>   communication packet is too large.**

[...]

> Both the client and the server have
>   their own max_allowed_packet variable,
>   so if you want to handle big packets,
>   you must increase this variable both
>   in the client and in the server.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html

Not sure how mysql_query return value is affected by this but it's worth investigating. Setting it in `my.cnf` to see if it fixes the problem would be the best place to start.

Comment: Worth investigating indeed. How do I find out what the PHP client's `max_allowed_packet` is? It's clearly not something on the server, because the query is very short.

Comment: I believe you need to issue a SQL statement through mysql_query along the lines of `SET @@max_allowed_packet=NUM` I think you can use abbreviated notation such as `64MB` but I haven't tried it.

Comment: @Radu: I'm not sure how to *view* the client setting. You could try `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';` The mysql client default is 16MB so that might also be true for the PHP client. I'm not sure of that one.

Comment: This is strange. I ran `SET @@max_allowed_packet=64M` then when it got to the query which made `mysql_query()` return `TRUE`, I received the following error: `PHP Error (2): mysql_query(): 57 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource`. It tried to make the query on the resource that I used to run the `max_allowed_packet` query, but it suddenly became invalid. Also, this happens from time to time. I mean, I still get the `TRUE` thing, but now I also get this.

Comment: The result set should be around 0.4 MB large, by the way. And the query is really small. I think it's unlikely to be the `max_allowed_packet`. Also, when I had `max_allowed_packet` problems, I got a different error... Don't remember which one it was, but it had something about the max packet size in it.

Comment: @Radu: I see. Well, it was worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query doesn't return FALSE, let alone TRUE. It returns a resource id that if equates to zero, con be taken as FALSE. My example is to illustrate boolean results

```
$resource = mysql_query($query, $handle);
if (!$resource) throw some exception;
if (!$resource && strpos($query, 'SELECT')) {
throw new Exception('mysql_query() returned TRUE for SELECT');
}
```

[PHP Booleans](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Comment: mysql_query doesn't return FALSE, let alone TRUE. It returns a resource id that if equates to zero, con be taken as FALSE. My example is to illustrate boolean results.

Comment: Steve, next time, please edit you answer and enhance it.  I have done it for you this time and up voted it.

Answer (score -2):

For `SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN` and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

For other type of SQL statements, `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP`, etc, `mysql_query()` returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on error.

> (from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

You say that SELECTs are returning boolean true?  Not just a resource that isn't zero :) ?

Comment: this doens't explain why its select returns true

Comment: Yes, it's `TRUE`. Checked with `===`.

Comment: voter weirdness yet again. Copying the manual that states exactly what the OP already knows doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I can't be certain but I don't remember reading the "only in a select statement" part when I answered the Q, and it's certainly been edited since.  Regardless, it does seem like a useless answer with the current question text.

Answer (score -2):

What James was trying to say is that the function mysql_query() simply returns true if the query has been taken and executed properly. It has nothing to do with the results the query yields.

If you want to actually fetch the results, use mysql_fetch_assoc()/ mysql_fetch_array()/ mysql_results().