# Impossible MySQL return value

Tags: php, mysql

This question is similar to this one: [Why does mysql_query() return TRUE with a SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208156/why-does-mysql-query-return-true-with-a-select-statement). I execute a SELECT mysql query in php, but it returns true. I've been starting at it for half an hour now and I'm completely positive it is a select query and it returns true. The obvious fix for the similar question was to check if the connection was still alive. The difference for me is, the mysql_error is empty. Here are the parts of my code that cause the error:

```
public function query($query, $params = array())
{
    $params['prefix'] = 'unpirate_';

    foreach($params as $key => $param)
    {
        $query = str_replace('{' . $key . '}',
            mysql_real_escape_string($param), $query);
    }

    echo($query);
    return mysql_query($query, $this->conn) or $this->error($query);
}

public function fetch_all($query, $params = array())
{
    $result = $this->query($query, $params);

    if($result === true)
        die('"' . mysql_error() . '"');
    (...)
}
```

The query that is echo'd is a valid query (SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE event_id = "54") and the only other thing that is echo'd is "", thus the result is true and the mysql_error is empty. Do you guys have any idea what is going on? Please correct me if my conclusion is not right.

PHP version: PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jun 13 2012 17:19:58)

MySQL version: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.24, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

Comment: tip: your escaping sequence is potentially hazardous. m_r_e_s() should be the very **LAST** thing done to a string before you use the string in a query. You're doing a str_replace on it, which could potentially UNDO the escaping and still leave you open to injection attacks. Not likely in this particular case, but it's still something to point out.

Comment: @MarcB I'm not sure how str_replace can undo my escaping. Can you give an example of a $query and $params that could possibly result in a SQL injection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return mysql_query($query, $this->conn) or $this->error($query);
```

Your return value is an OR statement.

What's happening is that PHP is evaluating the OR and returning the value of that, rather than the code itself; because there's data in the first part, it's evaluating to true, and returning a boolean true.

Try:

```
$retVal = mysql_query($query, $this->conn);
if (false === $retVal) {
    return $this->error($query);
}
return $retVal;
```

Comment: @niomaster - the only reason I spotted it is because I spent a day tracking down an identical problem a couple of weeks back. My hair still hasn't grown back in.

Comment: But now that I think about it, error echo's all sorts of things, invokes die at the end and doesn't return anything. So the question remains, why does it evaluate to true?

Comment: It's the 'or' part that's being evaluated. Essentially, it's turning the return statement into 'Does mysql_query contain something OR does mysql_error contain something', and of course one or the other will.

Comment: Actually I didn't mean mysql_error. Let's assume mysql_query returns false, which it should. Then $this->error($query) should have to evaluate to true, which it doesn't, because it terminates the script. Why?

Comment: Well, in the example you've given, you say that the SQL statement is a valid one; have you tried it with one you know won't work? I suspect, if your error() function includes a die(), that query() will either return `true` or error() will be called and execution will stop.