# MySQL - select count returns true

Tags: php, mysql, select, return, return-value

I am trying to determine whether an email is aready in my database or not. For this purpose I write this piece of code:

```
$query_checkmail = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE email = ?;";
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query_checkmail))
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_POST["email"]);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result, mysqli_fetch_all($result));
echo "</pre>";
```

Since I expect the query to return 0 because the email should not be in the database, the output is this (from `var_dump`):

```
bool(true)
NULL
```

I do not understand why I do not get a mysqli result object with the value 0 but instead the boolean value true which always triggers a PHP Warning in the logs if I want to check it.

I had a normal `SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = ?;";` before and got the same result. I thought with COUNT I could prevent this but my attempt has obviously failed.

I also found this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208156/why-does-mysql-query-return-true-with-a-select-statement) but unfortunatly it did not help my to solve my problem of getting to know whether the value already exists or not.

Any help is highly appreciated. If this information is not enough I will provide the missing bits immediatly.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what would you do after you had established whether or not the email exists?

Comment: This is the process of adding a new user. I must not have a user with this specific email address since it has to be unique as it is part of the login credentials and therefore I have to check if there is already a user with this email adress. If yes I return an error, if not I can carry on. I get `TRUE` as a result even if there is no one with this mail adress and not `0` which I need

Comment: Just establish a UNIQUE key and submit the email. the result of the insert will tell you whether the email existed or not

Comment: You're getting `true` because `mysqli_stmt_execute()` returns a boolean. This just means that the query was successfully executed, it has nothing to do with the results fetched in that query (see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php), specifically under "return values"). The `NULL` value comes from you putting in a boolean into [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), which expects a mysqli_result, not a boolean.

Comment: I see the point Qirel, nice name btw. I very this, if it works, post it as an answer to get an upvote and accetance :) Verified it. I would gladly accept this as your answer :)

Comment: By the way, you can also execute a query like `SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=?` and just count the rows, as MySQLi offers a solid `num_rows` constant if you find that easier, see [`mysqli_stmt_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) (which on PDO actually isn't as solid!) ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The count itself doesn't return a boolean true or false, you're checking against a variable assigned from `mysqli_stmt_execute()`, which returns a boolean. This has nothing to do with the results of the query. If you'll read the documentation on this function, specifically the return values of `mysqli_stmt_execute()`, you'll see that they are either `true` or `false`, so there is no surprise that a `var_dump()` of that would return a boolean.

If you want the actual count, you have to use `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()` and `mysqli_stmt_fetch()` to get the results of the count. This would produce the correct results. The manuals of this would show examples of that if you are unsure how to use these functions.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

As for the `NULL`, it's because you're passing a boolean into the [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) function, which expects a mysqli_result, while you're giving it a boolean from the above-mentioned reasons.

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_stmt_execute returns true or false, you should use mysqli_stmt_get_result after the excute to retrieve the data

i copied sample code from PHP.NET

```
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
foreach ($row as $r)
{
print "$r ";
}
print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Though your code does not help me the text does. See my edit on Quirels answer fot the code that fixed my problem. But thank you for your answer :) I suggest you update your code to match the question

Answer (score 0):

I suggest You to use PDO instead of mysqli. First make a connection, and then:

```
    $stm = $pdo->prepare("select count(*) from user where email = :email");
    $stm->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if ($stm->execute()) {
        $c = $stm->fetchColumn();           
    echo $c;       
    }
```

Comment: This might work, but I do not like PDO and never use it and to stay consistent in my many lines of Code I can not  use this for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MeekroDB, is the perfect php-mysql library. For example, with this code line you get similar result:

```
$user = DB::query("SELECT UserId FROM user WHERE email = %s",$email);
$count = DB::count();
```

As you can see, the code is cleaner and easy to write. Meekro is free and opensource: http://meekro.com/quickstart.php